# Import tab separated CSV, tab delimiter not recognized

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I have tab separated csv files which I want to transform to xlsx. So each csv should be transformed to a xlsx. Filename should be the same. However, the files are tab separated. For example, see this test file screenshot:

[image: ex11]

When I run my code (I created a subfolder xlsx before):

```
Sub all()

   Dim sourcepath As String
   Dim sDir As String
   Dim newpath As String
    
    sourcepath = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test\"
    newpath = sourcepath & "xlsx\"
    
    'make sure subfolder xlsx was created before

    sDir = Dir$(sourcepath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
        Workbooks.Open (sourcepath & sDir)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=Replace(Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")), sourcepath, newpath) & "xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
        End With
        
        sDir = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```

it does work, but when I look into the excel file:

[image: ex2]

I can see that the tab separator was not detected. I think my local settings are that the separator is a semi-colon and that's why it is not working. Now I wanted to set dataType to xlDelimited and tab to True, with changing the one line to:

```
Workbooks.Open (Spath & sDir), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
```

I also tried

```
Workbooks.Open (Spath & sDir, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True)
```

or

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:=Spath & sDir, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
```

But this leads to an error message. I then tried another approach, where I set the delimiter to Chr(9) (tab) and local to false:

```
Sub all()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strDir As String
    
    strDir = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.csv")
    
    Do While strFile <> ""
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strDir & strFile, Delimiter:=Chr(9), Local:=False)
    With wb
        .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xlsx"), 51
        .Close True
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing
    strFile = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

It does not lead to an error. But when I open the file, it looks like:

[image: ex2]

So again same problem, the tab separator is not recognized. How can I fix this?

(I also tried it with local:True together with Delimiter:=Chr(9), but same problem and I also tried it with adding Format:=6)

I tried it this way with csv as I did not want to go the same way with txt file extension. Reason is that using csv easily allows special language characters like "ö" and "ü". So that is why I wanted to convert csv to xlsx and not use the workaround of using txt instead, as I then run into the problem that when I try to convert txt to xlsx certain special characters are not properly recognised and I hope to avoid this problem with using csv.

The csv (or actually these are tsv, because they have the tab as separator and not semi-colon) files have different columns. So could be one csv file has 5 columns, the other 6 and the datatypes vary too.

EDIT:

In repsonse to EEMs answer:

Check this Test.csv file, it looks like this:

[image: ex4]

Separated by tab. Not semi-colon.

When I run the code (plus adding .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "." to the code) and check the resulting xlsx file it looks like this:

[image: ex2]

Values in the second column (ColumnÄ), like 9987.5 are correctly transformed to 9987,5. But values in the last column (ColumnI) are wrongly transformed. This is my problem now. (I dont know why special character does not get transformed correctly, as in my original files this does work.)

Comment: You should be able to use the ribbon command 'Text to columns' under the Data menu to process the worksheet; set it as delimited and include 'Tab' as a delimiter. Record a macro to more easily get the VBA code required.

Comment: Answer update to care for the new info about numeric data, please test.

Comment: Thanks for your ongoing support and I will accept your answer. However, one last question: In the resulting xlsx files the sheetname for all files is "Sheet1". I would like to carry this over from the filename. So that the resulting sheetname is as the filename is (without the .xslx). Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @RonRosenfeld, files with `.csv` extension will be opened by excel as a text file with tab delimiters.

Also the following assumption is not accurate:

> Option1 txt is not a way for me, as I face a new problem that UTF-8
> special characters, like äö and so are not properly imported.

The handling of the characters or `code page` has nothing to do with the extension of the files, instead it's managed by the `Origin` parameter of the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) or by the [TextFilePlatform property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.textfileplatform) of the  `QueryTable` object.

Therefore unless the files are renamed with a extension different than `csv` the [Workbooks.OpenText method] will not be effective.

The solution proposed below, uses the `QueryTable` object and consist of two procedures:

1. Tab_Delimited_UTF8_Files_Save_As_Xlsx

- Sets the source and target folder
- Creates the `xlsx` folder if not present
- Gets all `csv` files in the source folder

2. Open_Csv_As_Tab_Delimited_Then_Save_As_Xls

- Process each `csv` files
- Adds a workbook to hold the `Query Table`
- Imports the csv file
- Deletes the Query
- Saves the File as `xlsx'

**EDIT I** These lines were added to ensure the conversion of the numeric data:

```
                .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
                .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
```

**EDIT II** A Few changes to rename the worksheet (marked as '@ )

Tested with this csv file:

[image]

Generated this `xlsx' file:

[image]

Hopefully, it should be straightforward to add these procedure to you project, let me know of any problem or question you might have with the resources used.

```
Sub Tab_Delimited_UTF8_Files_Save_As_Xlsx()
Dim sFile As String
Dim sPathSrc As String, sPathTrg As String
Dim sFilenameSrc As String, sFilenameTrg As String
Dim bShts As Byte, exCalc As XlCalculation
    
Rem sPathSrc = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test\"
    sPathTrg = sPathSrc & "xlsx\"
    
    Rem Excel Properties OFF
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        exCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .CalculateBeforeSave = False
        bShts = .SheetsInNewWorkbook
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    End With

    Rem Validate Target Folder
    If Len(Dir$(sPathTrg, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir sPathTrg

    Rem Process Csv Files
    sFile = Dir$(sPathSrc & "*.csv")
    Do Until Len(sFile) = 0
        
        sFilenameSrc = sPathSrc & sFile
        sFile = Left(sFile, -1 + InStrRev(sFile, ".csv"))    '@
        sFilenameTrg = sPathTrg & sFile & ".xlsx"            '@
        
        Call Open_Csv_As_Tab_Delimited_Then_Save_As_Xls(sFile, sFilenameSrc, sFilenameTrg)    '@
        
        sFile = Dir$
    
    Loop

    Rem Excel Properties OFF
    With Application
        .SheetsInNewWorkbook = bShts
        .Calculation = exCalc
        .CalculateBeforeSave = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
    End Sub
```

…

```
Sub Open_Csv_As_Tab_Delimited_Then_Save_As_Xls(sWsh As String, sFilenameSrc As String, sFilenameTrg As String)    '@
Dim Wbk As Workbook
    
    Rem Workbook - Add
    Set Wbk = Workbooks.Add
    With Wbk
        
        With .Worksheets(1)

            Rem QueryTable - Add
            With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & sFilenameSrc, Destination:=.Cells(1))
                
                Rem QueryTable - Properties
                .SaveData = True
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
                .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
                .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
                .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                .TextFilePlatform = 65001               'Unicode (UTF-8)
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                
                Rem QueryTable - Delete
                .Delete
            
            End With
        
            Rem Rename Worksheet    '@
            On Error Resume Next    '@ Ignore error in case the Filename is not valid as Sheetname
            .Name = sWsh            '@
            On Error GoTo 0         '@
        
        End With

        Rem Workbook - Save & Close
        .SaveAs Filename:=sFilenameTrg, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        .Close
    
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: I copied your code and adjusted the sPathSrc to my folder (I did pay attention to have another "\" at the end, so not only ...\Test but ...\Test\. So exactly as yours is. When I try to run your code, I get the error runtime error 1004 excel cannot access workboox.xlsx and the debugger marks Set Wbk = Workbooks.Add(Template:="Workbook"). What is the problem here?

Comment: It may have to do with my machine settings, I do have a custom workbook by default, apologies for that. Please change it to `Workbooks.Add`, try and let me know.

Comment: First of all a big thanks for your ongoing support and your fast answer. I tried it and it does work, however, there is one problem: The resulting excel files have the wrong decimal delimiter. So in the original csv files numbers are displayed as for example 9984.5 In my excel this is shown too. However, for further analysis I need excel to show me a 9985,5 So a "," not a ".". I cannot change this manually in each file.

Comment: What is the decimal separator your excel uses?

Comment: The csv files have "." as decimal separator and your excel uses also ".", the files are imported with a ".", but you need the csv files to be imported with "," as decimal separator. It's this correct?

Comment: No. My excel uses ",". So in my csv there is a "." as decimal separator. Yes, correct. When I open the xlsx files after running your code, I can see it displayed with "." and I can see that excel does not recognize this as numeric. So I need excel to display it with "," (and recognize it as numeric, but I guess this would be done automatically). I tried to set .TextFileDecimalSeparator.

Comment: When I set it to "." it does not change anything. When I set it to "," then I do get correct results for some columns, so 9987,5 is displayed (which is correct), but other columns are transferred falsely. This happens in both cases ("," or "." set): For one column there were entries before like 0.000 or 1000.000. Actually like the 9987.5 However, the 1000.000 are transformed to 1.000.000 which is wrong. I don't know why this happens, as in both cases, so 9987.5 and 1000.000 the "." is the decimal separator and there is only one "." in the original data (1000.000).

Comment: So I do not get why it changes 1000.000 to 1.000.000. And as I said, it happens no matter if I set TextFileDecimalSeparator to "," or ".". I would expect that when I set it to "," then 9987.5 get transformed to 9987,5 and 1.000 gets transformed to 1,000. But 1.000 is transformed to 1.000.000.

Comment: I guess that reason is that in the one column there are only at max two digits after the separator (9987.5) but in the other case there are 3 (1.000) and this influences it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224680/discussion-between-eem-and-berthobe).

Comment: Thanks for your ongoing support and I will accept your answer. However, one last question: In the resulting xlsx files the sheetname for all files is "Sheet1". I would like to carry this over from the filename. So that the resulting sheetname is as the filename is (without the .xslx). Is that possible?

Comment: I tried to run your code. When I run it I get an error message runtime error 7 not enough space and the debugger marks the line .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False However, I do have enough space and when I run the old version from before the update with the file/sheetname, it still works. Sorry for annoying.

Comment: It happens already in the first file and that one is not really large.

Comment: You are right, it’s annoying. I tested the code ( +70 different files ) and it ran Ok. Nevertheless, I moved the worksheet rename after the query refresh. Try this version.

Answer (score 1):

With a delimited file that has a csv extension, Excel's `Open` and vba `Workbooks.Open` and `Workbooks.OpenText` methods will always assume that the delimiter is a comma, no matter what you put into the argument.

1. You can change the file extension (eg to `.txt`), and then the `.Open` method should work.
2. You could read it into a TextStream object and parse it line by line in VBA
3. You can **Import** the file rather than **Open**ing the file.

- You could use `Power Query` to import it.
- Or you could use a variation of the code below, which was just generated by the macro recorder, so you'll have to clean it up and adapt it a bit to your specifics.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;D:\Users\Ron\Desktop\myFile.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$12"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "weather_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. Option1 txt is not a way for me, as I face a new problem that UTF-8 special characters, like äö and so are not properly imported. One question regarding option3, as this seems to be the best solution for me: How would that look, to import it rather opening? Regarding PowerQuery: I do not have just 1 file, but quite a lot. Does PowerQuery allow to make this for quite many files in a reasonable way or do I have to do it manually for each file? That is not an option for me.

Comment: The vba code looks good, however I think my abilities are too limitedto adjust things like .TextFileColumnDataTypes dynamically. I have a lot of different files. They do not have the same datatypes and so. Also the range is not the same in each file.

Comment: @BertHobe I don't understand your objection with regard to the datatypes.  You aren't trying to set them in your existing code.  Why should you need to set them in this code?

Comment: Well I thought because of  .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)? So that explicitely states the datatype and I thought I have to do this and specify it? But I do not know, what column is string or integer or so? So I don't know how to put this into my loop.

Comment: @BertHobe I'm pretty sure it's an optional argument.

Comment: And how do I implement it when the range (where the data is) is different in each file?

Comment: @BertHobe I thought your data is in a file?

Comment: My data is a file. However, I do have lots of different files, the range is always different, so the number of rows and columns differ, so does the filename.

Comment: So my problem is I do not know how to put this into my code to make it work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224424/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-berthobe).

Comment: I updated my question and tried to implement your vba code.

Comment: @BertHobe a quick peek indicates that probably your connection string syntax is incorrect. Looks like there's at least a missing semicolon.

Comment: @BertHobe I wouldn't expect that to work. To me it looks like the semicolon is part of the string and not a seperator.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I tried to get it working with a simple file. But I get an error message. It should be the same as your code, but it simply does not work.

Comment: @BertHobe Try recording a macro when you **import** the file manually from Excel, for a single file. That should provide proper syntax.

Comment: I already tried that, but the result was similiar to yours and I wasn't able to implement it into my code.

Comment: @BertHobe Does it work for a single file when you use that recorded macro?

Comment: Problem with that is that the resulting code contains a lot of "hard-coded" values, like column names are already included. Furthermore it does not look like yours, it differs, for example ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add is used. My VBA is knowledge is not sufficient to automize it.

Comment: @BertHobe This method is arguably the most efficient and most easily customizable method, but its implementation in your environment seems to require a level of VBA knowledge which you have not yet acquired.  And I don't see any hard-coded column names in the code generated, so I really don't know what the issue is.  If the issue is the column names in the file, that you need to change to some standard; or put certain columns in a ceertain order, that was not addressed in your initial question. If something else, please enlighten me.

Comment: @BertHobe wrt to Option #1, if you use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method (instead of the `Workbooks.Open` method) you can specify a UTF-8 code page as the origin, which will eliminate the objection you made.

Comment: My question here was quite clear, as I already wrote in the initial question that here I want to go the way with CSV and not with TXT. So here this question is about how to import csv to xlsx and get it working if it is a tsv and not csv. My files are not special. If someone gets it working for two example files it works for me. However, my problem is that I do not know how to implement it into my loop. Your code snippet you posted is not really complete and does not help me. That is the problem.

Comment: @BertHobe That doesn't really answer my question. So far as the txt file solution, copying the file to your system TEMP directory and changing the file type suffix is easily done in VBA (see the `Environ` (to determine the folder), `Name` (to copy with a changed name, and `Kill` (to delete the txt file when you are done with it) are methods you could embed in your DO loop to implement  #1.  Just a suggestion since you can't seem to get the Data Connection method working, and I can't understand your issues with regard to "hard coded column names".

Answer (score 1):

Using the ADODB.Stream object, you can create a user-defined function.

```
Sub all()

    Dim sourcepath As String
    Dim sDir As String
    Dim newpath As String
    Dim vResult As Variant
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Fn As String
     sourcepath = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Test\"
     newpath = sourcepath & "xlsx\"
     
     'make sure subfolder xlsx was created before
    
     sDir = Dir$(sourcepath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
         'Workbooks.Open (sourcepath & sDir)
         'use adodb.stream
         vResult = TransToTextWithCsvUTF_8(sourcepath & sDir)
         Fn = Replace(sDir, ".csv", ".xlsx")
         
         Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
         With Wb
            Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vResult, 1) + 1, UBound(vResult, 2) + 1) = vResult
            .SaveAs Filename:=newpath & Fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
         End With
         
         sDir = Dir$
     Loop
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function TransToTextWithCsvUTF_8(strFn As String) As Variant
    Dim vR() As String
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, j As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim objStream  As Object
    Dim strRead As String
    Dim vSplit, vRow
    Dim s As String
    
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    With objStream
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile strFn
         strRead = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
    
    vSplit = Split(strRead, vbCrLf)
    r = UBound(vSplit)
    c = UBound(Split(vSplit(0), vbTab, , vbTextCompare))
    ReDim vR(0 To r, 0 To c)
    
    For i = 0 To r
        vRow = Split(vSplit(i), vbTab, , vbTextCompare)
        If UBound(vRow) = c Then 'if it is empty line, skip it
            For j = 0 To c
                If IsNumeric(vRow(j)) Then
                    s = Format(vRow(j), "#,##0.000")
                    s = Replace(s, ".", "+")
                    s = Replace(s, ",", ".")
                    s = Replace(s, "+", ",")
                    vR(i, j) = s
                Else
                    vR(i, j) = vRow(j)
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    TransToTextWithCsvUTF_8 = vR
    
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I copied your code and adjusted the sPathSrc to my folder (I did pay attention to have another "\" at the end, so not only ...\Test but ...\Test\. So exactly as yours is. When I try to run your code, I get the error runtime error 9 index out of valid area and the debugger marks vR(i, j) = vRow(j) ?

Comment: @BertHobe, The error may have occurred because the number of tab-separated characters in the text document is different. Probably because it is less than 9 in the errored line.

Comment: Well each txt document can have a different number of columns?

Comment: @BertHobe, i edited answer. If there are empty lines, skip it.  `If UBound(vRow) = c Then`

Comment: I copied the code and adjusted the filepath and created the xlsx subfolder. Then I run your code. When I run it, it opens a file and saves it as xlsx.xlsx. The next file then again is tried to be saved under this filename and I am asked if I want to replace the file. This does not work. I need the filenames to be there and it has to work with the loop.

Comment: @BertHobe,I think your code is correct, and I didn't review it.

Comment: +1 for your ongoing support. I tried it and it works, however I run into the problem with decimal and thousand separtor. So in my csv there are numbers like 9987.5 They need to be converted to 9987,5. And numbers like 1.000 that denot pieces are not properly transformed, they are transformed to 1.000.000. So is there a way to set decimal separator to "." and thousand separator to ","? Or get it working in another way.

Comment: @BertHobe, i edited `Function TransToTextWithCsvUTF_8()'. However, the thousands and decimals are different for each country, so I don't know which country type your system follows, so I replaced the numbers with letters.

Answer (score 1):

This method uses File System Object and Text Stream to change from tab delimited to comma delimited. Select Microsoft Scripting Runtime inside of Tools/References to make available the library used. If semicolon delimited also does not open correctly, you can replace third parameter of REPLACE function in line *fileContents = Replace(fileContents, vbTab, ";")* with comma and try again. Note we are creating a .csv file with *Set textStreamObj = fileSystemObj.CreateTextFile("filePath2.csv")*, not overwriting our original.

```
Option Explicit

Sub changeDelimitedMarker()
    Dim fileSystemObj As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim textStreamObj As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim fileContents As String
    
    Set fileSystemObj = New FileSystemObject
    Set textStreamObj = fileSystemObj.OpenTextFile("filePath1.csv")
    fileContents = textStreamObj.ReadAll
    textStreamObj.Close
    fileContents = Replace(fileContents, vbTab, ",")
    Set textStreamObj = fileSystemObj.CreateTextFile("filePath2.csv")
    textStreamObj.Write fileContents
    textStreamObj.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Well my aim is to get it from csv to xlsx. So not filePath2.csv, but xlsx as a result.

Comment: @BertHobe ty for +1, remember a .csv file can be opened by directly by workbook then saved as .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

The `Text to Columns` should work for this:

```
Sub all()

   Dim sourcepath As String
   Dim sDir As String
   Dim newpath As String
    
    sourcepath = "C:\Users\snapier\Downloads\Test\"
    newpath = sourcepath & "xlsx\"
    
    'make sure subfolder xlsx was created before

    sDir = Dir$(sourcepath & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
        Workbooks.Open (sourcepath & sDir)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
            .UsedRange.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False
        End With
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=Replace(Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")), sourcepath, newpath) & "xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
        End With
        
        sDir = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```